# Global nav with dynamic links across multiple sites

Tags: database

We are currently working on using Craft to build out new versions of our site (in-house) and we have multiple sites that will share a global nav. Is there a way for one site to access the data in another site to update the global nav dynamically? I'm not sure if it's possible but I also know Craft is pretty magical.

The parent domain link and child domain link will hardly never change so that can stay static content; more so wondering about accessing the data in the child domain from parent/sibling sites.

```
example structure

parent domain link
  |-- child domain link
  |   |_
  |     |-- dynamic links
  |     |-- dynamic links
  |     |-- dynamic links
  |
  |-- child domainlink
  |   |_
  |     |-- dynamic links
  |     |-- dynamic links
  |     |-- dynamic links
  |
  |-- child domain link
     |_
       |-- dynamic links
       |-- dynamic links
       |-- dynamic links
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, that's not possible with Craft itself. That might be possible in Craft 3, as cloning sites will be an option -- though all of your sites would also have to be in Craft. Not sure if sharing information between sites will exist in C3 or not though.

You COULD use Craft to create the navigation fairly easily. Then you could create a blank template (not extending your base layout) that only contains the navigation, and then loading that via AJAX on the other sites into a nav container div.